# RxJava2: Using Flowable with zipWith

Tags: rx-java2

I'm trying to make the following code work me but something is wrong, here is a snippet:

```
private void myMethod() {
Flowable.fromIterable(cache)
.zipWith(this::doesExist, (record, exist) -> {
    // do stuff
    return true;
}).subscrib();
}

private Flowable<Boolean> doesExist(CacheRecord record) {
    // Do something
    return Flowable.just(true);
}
```

This doesn't compile, any idea?

**UPDATE**:
Any thoughts about the following snippet:

```
Flowable.fromIterable(m_cache) // 
.flatMapCompletable(cachedStation -> { 
    return Single.zip(Single.just(cachedStation), doesIssueExist(cachedStation), (record, exist) -> { 
    System.out.println(cachedStation + ", " + exist); 
    return true; 
}).toCompletable(); 
}).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `doesExist` method requires a `CacheRecord` as a parameter. But the method reference you have given `this::doesExist` sends an instance of `Subscriber<? super Object>` that's why the incompatible type error is showing.

The expanded form of your method is given below.

```
  private void myMethod() {
    Flowable.fromIterable(cache)
            .zipWith(new Publisher<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void subscribe(Subscriber<? super Object> s) {
                    doesExist(s);
                }
            }, (record, exist) -> {
                // do stuff
                return true;
            }).subscribe();
 }
```

Here, the first parameter to `zipWith`

```
  new Publisher<Object>() {
        @Override
         public void subscribe(Subscriber<? super Object> s) {
                doesExist(s);
            }
   }
```

is what you have shortened as `this::doesExist`

As you can see the `zipWith` requires the first parameter a `Publisher`, and you have created an anonymous Publisher, and in the `subscribe` method you are calling `doesExist(s)` by sending the `Subscriber<? super Object> s`, which is not the required type.  Your method reference statement `this::doesExist` does exactly the above operation and that's why the `incompatible type` error is shown by the compiler.

If you are trying to `zip` the Flowable with the flowable returned by `doesExist` method, you can directly call it, without method reference, by passing a valid `CacheRecord` object as follows

```
Flowable.fromIterable(cache)
        .zipWith(doesExist(anotherCache), (record, exist) -> {
            // do stuff
            return true;
        }).subscribe();
```

*Note: See [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) for more information*

**Update**: If you are trying to pass the items emitted by `fromIterable` to `doesExist` method and get combined result `boolean` and `cacheRecord`, then

create a holder class as follows

```
class CacheRecordResult {
    CacheRecord cacheRecord;
    boolean isExist;

    public CacheRecordResult(CacheRecord cacheRecord, boolean isExist) {
        this.cacheRecord = cacheRecord;
        this.isExist = isExist;
    }
   }
```

Then subscribe to `CacheRecordResult` as follows

```
  private void myMethod() {
    Flowable.fromIterable(cache)
          .flatMap(cacheRecord -> doesExist(cacheRecord)
                  .map(exist -> new CacheRecordResult(cacheRecord, exist)))
          .subscribe(cacheRecordResult -> {
                CacheRecord cacheRecord = cacheRecordResult.cacheRecord;
                boolean isExist = cacheRecordResult.isExist;
            });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! 
How can I call `doesExist` with elements that are emitted by `Flowable.fromIterable` ?

Comment: This doesn't work:
`Flowable.fromIterable(cache).zipWith(cacheRecord -> doesExist(cacheRecord), (record, exist) -> ...`

Comment: Are you trying to get each elemt from `fromIterable` and call `doesExist` with each of them? In that case you can't use `zipWith`

Comment: Yep, that's my goal.

Comment: At the end are you subscribing to a boolean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184520/discussion-between-shvalb-and-sarath-kn).